# "Authentication key already exists" error while adding computer to cluster proxmox

Tags: cluster, proxmox

I had 2 computers running proxmox which were set up in a cluster called "cluster1". For simplicity the computers were named computer1 and computer2. computer1 was the primary, and computer2 was added to cluster1 after. They worked and communicated fine in the cluster.

I wiped computer1 and reinstalled proxmox on it. I then created a cluster on computer1 called "cluster1" again using the command `pvecm create cluster1`. I tried adding computer2 to "cluster1" again using the command `pvecm add cluster1` but I get the following error:

> Authentication key already exists

How can I add computer2 to cluster1 if it still has data from a previously created cluster called cluster1? At least I believe it still has data since the authentication key already exists. Is there a way to remove all previous clusters? I tried running the command `pvecm delnode computer1` while on computer2 but it still gives me the same error when I try to add computer2 to cluster1.

I contemplated wiping and reinstalling proxmox but from a troubleshooting standpoint this would not be a very good solution.

Comment: I am not an expert in Proxmox, but with my limited exposure I would recommend reinstalling computer1 and delete it from the cluster following this url [link](https://pve.proxmox.com/wiki/Proxmox_VE_4.x_Cluster#Remove_a_cluster_node) . Then add the reinstalled computer1 to cluster1.

Answer (score 0):

Wrong commands.

You need this:

1. login to computer1

run:

```
pvecm create CLUSTERNAME
```

Login to computer2

```
pvecm add computer1
```

or

```
pvecm add computer1_IP_address
```

Login to computer3

```
pvecm add computer1
```